# Selection field type elements cannot be shown. How to properly add a custom entity representation to Sulu form?

Tags: symfony, sulu

Following by Sulu [documentation](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.0/book/extend-admin.html#selection-field-type), I try to add selection field type to display collection type resource (Room object) in admin form. Currently, I can select these elements from list,

[select element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3wWG.png)

[selected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDWnI.png)

but after form submit and reload any record cannot be shown, despite that the Room object exist in Event entity:

[empty list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O3MV.jpg)

What I do wrong?

Code:

**sulu_admin.yaml**

```
sulu_admin:
...

# Registering Selection Field Types in this section
field_type_options:
    selection:
        room_selection:
            default_type: list_overlay
            resource_key: rooms
            types:
                list_overlay:
                    adapter: table
                    list_key: rooms
                    display_properties:
                        - name
                    icon: su-clock
                    label: 'app.rooms'
                    overlay_title: 'app.rooms'
```

**event_details.xml**

```
        <property name="rooms" type="room_selection">
             <meta>
                 <title>app.rooms</title>
             </meta>
        </property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api response should just contain a flat list of room ids for `rooms`. Assuming you have an `Event` entity with a `$rooms` property, add a `public function getRoomIds() {}` to your `Event` entity and add the `@VirtualProperty("rooms")` annotation to that method. Probably you have to add the `@Exclude` annotation to `public function getRooms() {}`

**EDIT:**

I just tried it, if you have an entity like the following, it works as expected. If it's still not working, maybe you have a problem with your jms serializer config.

```
/**
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $otherProperty;

    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Room>
     */
    private $rooms;

    public function getRooms(): Collection
    {
        return $this->rooms;
    }

    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("rooms")
     */
    public function getRoomIds(): array
    {
        return $this->rooms->map(function (Room $room) {
            return $room->getId();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Following your instructions my entity's code looks like:
`
/**
 * @Serializer\Exclude()
 * @return Collection|Room[]
 */
public function getRooms():? Collection
{
    return $this->rooms;
}

/**
 * @VirtualProperty("rooms")
 */
public function getRoomIds(): array
{
    $list = [];
    foreach ($this->rooms as $room) {
        $list[] = $room->getId();
    }
    return $list;
}
`
but it still not working.

Comment: What does the api response for `rooms` look like now?

Comment: No i meant this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O3MV.jpg ... Did this api response change after you changed your code? Also, do you get any javascript error in your console?